# How to prove the inequality arc length (AB) <= arc length (AC) + arc length(BC) for any point A,B,C on a cylinder?

Tags: inequality, arc-length, noneuclidean-geometry

I need to use the formula of arc length(r) = ((a-b)^2+(x-y)^2)^1/2 for point A =(a, x) and B=(b,y), but I don't know how to expand the inequality and prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why have you tagged "non-Euclidean geometry"?

Comment: I don't really know. I am having a non-Euclidean geometry class.